# xdotool keyboard automation

Tags: automation, xdotool

I'm new to coding in the linux operating system.  I had autohotkey on my windows system and I'm trying to figure out the best way to migrate this to Linux.  I'm looking to press one set of keys but send back a different set of keys that would populate on a webpage.  For example, if I wanted to use:

keydown (and then keyup) ctrl shift z and then send keydown/keyup m enter.

Using xdotool how would I write this code?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what that particular sequence, especially "keydown/keyup" is supposed to do, but `xdotool` looks like it will do anything you need.

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+z

xdotool key m; xdotool key KP_Enter
```

`xdotool key` does one character at a time. That's why it is invoked twice in the second line with the <kbd>;</kbd> telling your shell that these are two separate commands.

If what you want is to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and have the system emit <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, then your script would have to read the keyboard, detect your trigger phrase, and then run the second xdotool command above. That's a bit tricky to do when the window you're displaying is a web page in a browser, but see below. Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> might not be the best trigger phrase because it has special meaning in a terminal window and, perhaps, elsewhere.

However: If you're coming from AutoHotKey (AHK) and want similar functionality on Linux, then [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) is what you want.

What you get are phrases (you can define purely in the GUI), where pressing a hotkey or typing an abbreviation will cause the contents of your phrase to be typed or pasted into your application with the abbreviation optionally removed.

That's fairly similar to AHK.

When you need more control or more complexity, you have AutoKey scripts. These are also triggered by hotkeys and abbreviations, but instead of being written in an application specific language, they are written in Python 3 and have the full power of that language and all its extension modules available for your use.

AutoKey provides an API for generating keyboard and mouse events, using the clipboard, getting window information, and displaying dialogs.

Your two examples above would each need to be one line scripts:

```
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<shift>+z")
```

and

```
keyboard.send_keys("m<enter>")
```

In the first example, the <kbd>+</kbd> tells AutoKey to press those keys at the same time so that the first two keys act as modifiers. In the second example, there is no <kbd>+</kbd>, so the <kbd>m</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys are pressed sequentially.

In practice, the things your scripts type would usually be longer or determined by more logic.

Note: If you are using a release of Ubuntu prior to 20.04, you need to install AutoKey from GitHub to avoid getting a very old, unsupported version. It's quite easy to do in Ubuntu and instructions are available [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing#debian-and-derivatives).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am use to AHK.  I'm trying to convert this script that is in AHK to the linux version.  Autokey may be the best solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: another question.  how would you create a continuous loop in xdotool or autokey?  in python, you'd create a while loop, is it the same way?  thanks.

Comment: `xdotool` is one command sequence at a time (commands can be chained, but not looped), so you'd have to build a loop around it in a script or programming language. `AutoKey` scripts are written in Python which is a full programming language with loops and other flow control constructs you can use. The best way to do it depends on the task at hand. It can get a little difficult to debug complex scripts running within AutoKey because you usually don't have a terminal available to accept input or to print debugging info to. If you don't need to trigger with a key or phrase, it's not as useful.